# How to modify a function to call to the first function?

Tags: python, callback, thonny

I'm trying to work out how to modify `is_odd` so that it calls to `is_even` to determine if its argument is an odd integer

```
def is_even(n):
    if (n % 2 ==0):
        return("True")
    else:
        return("False")

def is_odd(n):
    if not(is_even):
        return("True")

print(is_odd(2))
```

This is the code I have at the moment but it's just returning with none.

Comment: `if not(is_even)` should be `if not(is_even(n))` You forgot to pass n to `is_even`

Comment: Why use the strings `"True"`/`"False"` instead of actual boolean values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally the Pythonic style for truthiness is

```
def is_even(n):
    return n % 2 == 0
```

While there are many ways to do what you want, a simple method is:

```
def is_odd(n):
    return is_even(n + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def is_even(n):
    if (n % 2 == 0):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def is_odd(n):
    return not is_even(n)

print(is_odd(2))
```